# custom change in front page

Tags: frontpage, settings-api

I want to remove the archive widget on the front page. How do I do it please?
The archive section is at the bottom of site.
[Kirkuk Now](http://kirkuknow.com/english)

Best Regards

Comment: What **Theme** are you using?

Comment: Ah, I see: Advanced Newspaper, from Gabfire Themes. As this is a commercial Theme, you should consult the support offerings of the Theme developer for Theme-specific support.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your site, then looking at the live demo of the theme ... and that archive section isn't hard-coded into the theme by default.

This potentially means one of two things:

1. You or someone managing your site added it
2. The archive widget is the "default" widget for some section and you haven't put anything else there yet.

### If you added the widget

Just go into Appearance » Widgets and remove it.

### If it's the default

Go into Appearance » Widgets and add an *empty* text widget to the empty widget container.  This should dump "nothing" into the widget area and prevent the defaults from firing up.